# ¿Cómo replicar un Postman en C# - Android?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, post, postman

Estoy intentando realizar un `Post` con `Xamarin.Android C#` para enviar una notificación de tipo Push utilizando Firebase Cloud Messaging FCM, pero Backend definitivamente no es lo mio.

Alguna idea de que sucede?

Me funciona en Postman pero no en C#. Lo intente de esta forma pero no me funciona:

```
async void SendNotification(string FCMbody, string FCMtitle)
        {
            try
            {
                
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var content = new StringContent(
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { body = FCMbody, title = FCMtitle }));
                var result = await client.PostAsync("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var resultpost = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Exp)
            {
                
            }
            
        }
```

El Post que intento replicar (y que si me funciona en Postman) es:

**URL:**

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type : application/json

Authorization: key= ****** my server key from firebase console **** (AAA...)
```

**Body (raw):**

```
{
    "to" : "AXzsfgW9khDdejg:APA91bHG3G4hlO0jGZk1djwEip2m9eHahAg4HNhCkfS-otj_EWHqbhZ2Il_3HQwK4yo9G4mhDpq7KFeeB0wDGiAmENGNqRfqB0yqFh8C43QRNIoNdNz",
    "data" : {
        "body" : "Test",
        "title" : "Title Test"
        
    }
}
```

Respuesta exitosa del post en Postman:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 12335220413087227,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:574839209297865%11976661f9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}
```

El error que me da en C# es (Yo tengo el Authorization Key, simplemente no se donde adjuntarlo):

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'The request was missing an Authentication Key. Please, refer to section "Authentication" of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Accept-Ranges: none
  Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
  Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
  Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
  Date: Sun, 20 Feb 2022 14:52:30 GMT
  Server: GSE
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  X-Android-Received-Millis: 1645368748316
  X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 401
  X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
  X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1645368748236
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Expires: Sun, 20 Feb 2022 14:52:30 GMT
}}
```

He revisado varios documentos pero son ejemplos diferentes:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/674fe4ce-5f07-417d-8ca8-9b92b60e3ac8/how-to-post-a-json-in-rest-service?forum=xamarinandroid

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458551/send-http-post-request-in-xamarin-forms-c-sharp

Comment: En C# normalmente uso Restsharp en lugar de HttpClient que muchos problemas me dio tiempo atrás, pero a primera vista, ¿no te falta incluir el header de Authorization? ¿Devuelve algún error al ejecutar tu código?

Comment: Entonces, tu pregunta es como adjuntar la autorization key al codigo que tenes... no? nada que ver con postman, android ni nada de eso...

Comment: Pues lo que intento es replicar un post exitoso de postman (que incluye el auth key), solo que no estoy seguro como hacerlo en C# (Xamarin.Android).

Pero si, tu comentario resume bien lo que necesito. Adjuntar el Auth y el Token del dispositivo